# How to get Postfix statistics of second instance?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix, email-server

I have a quick question. I have two instances of Postfix running on an Ubuntu server and I want to write some scripts to email our server admin Postfix statistics (queue count, sent, etc). How would I get that information on the second instance?

When I run the following command:

```
postqueue -p
```

Is that the information of the first instance, second or both? If its not information on the second instance, how would I get that information?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `postqueue` will give you information regarding your "primary" Postfix instance (where "primary" means "the instance using configuration files in the default location", which is generally `/etc/postfix`).

According to [the man page](http://www.postfix.org/postqueue.1.html), you can use the `-c` option to point `postqueue` at the configuration directory for your second instance.

Note that most of the postfix command line tools have a `-c` option.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the well-known `pflogsumm` script; it generates very complete statistics for each instance.

Answer (score 1):

For postfix version 2.6 and later, you can use `postmulti` shipped by postfix. Excerpt from [man 1 postmulti](http://www.postfix.org/postmulti.1.html):

> The  postmulti(1) command allows a Postfix administrator to manage multiple Postfix instances on a single host.
>
> postmulti(1) implements two fundamental modes of operation.  In  iterator  mode, it executes the same command for multiple Postfix instances. In life-cycle management mode, it adds  or  deletes  one  instance,  or changes the multi-instance status of one instance.

Thus for invoking postqueue of specific instance you can use **postmulti -x**, for example:

```
postmulti -i postfix-secondinstance -x postqueue -p
```